# Force override method if another method is overriden

Tags: c#

Is there a way to force the override of a virtual method if another method is overriden?

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual void A()
    { 
        // a default action called first
    }

    protected virtual void B()
    { 
        // a default action called second that,
        // if A was overriden, makes no sense
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks a lot for the Answers. It's very interresting to see how this could be achieved, but for my explicit case it's not critically important.

Also, i forgot to mention how those Methods would be used: (in BaseClass)

```
pulbic bool EditEntity(Guid id)
{
    A();

    // Some code that edits Entites

    B();
}
```

Comment: Noone forces you to override `GetHashCode` if `Equals` is overriden

Comment: The question is why `B` makes no sense anymore  if `A` was overriden.

Comment: It's a bad design not to override the other if you override one of them, and it will probably generate a warning (at least in some static analysis tool), but it's not prohibited by the language

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm editing relations with Entity Framework and the Default is that nothing will be done. Else there will be Checks called that are unneccessary. It's just an optimisation thing, not anything overly important.

Comment: make it abstract and don't implement the body of the methods? Then the derived class has to implement them

Comment: just create 2 different interfaces. one where you,  overrride one function.  and another where you override 2. now you need to choose which one to implement

Comment: @Default I don't want every derived class to implement it, just the ones that need to implement it. I've got abstract classes too.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't get what you want. You can either declare them as abstract, forcing descendants to implement both, or to declare them as virtual, in which case they can pick and choose which one to implement, either, or both. Or, perhaps, you should find a completely different way to do this? Since you're only asking about this problem it's hard to give any tips on alternatives. Could you elaborate on why you want to force none or both?

Comment: you could use reflection in the base method to detect whether it is being called from its own class and throw an exception if not

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's not that important, as i said: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028502/force-override-method-if-another-method-is-overriden?noredirect=1#comment46298765_29028502). They are Implementations for a base class, where i in A return the relations and remove them from the entity and i in B get the relations and add them properly. The default case is don't do anything, because there are no relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. But this makes me think how could you achieve the same concept?

The best idea I came up with was declaring an interface which had the package of methods to override.

```
 public interface IMyOverridablePackage
 {
     void A_Override();
     void B_Override();
 }
```

Then give the base class a protected method where the child class can explicitly override the set of methods.

```
protected void SetOverride(IMyOverridablePackage overridablePackage)
{
    _overridablePackage = overridablePackage;
}
```

So then here's two classes, one which does and one which does not override the set of methods:

```
 public class NotOverriding : MyBaseClass
 {
 }


public sealed class Overriding : MyBaseClass, IMyOverridablePackage
{
    public Overriding()
    {
        SetOverride(this);
    }

    void IMyOverridablePackage.A_Override()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Overriding.A_Override");            
    }

    void IMyOverridablePackage.B_Override()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Overriding.B_Override");
    }
}
```

And the implementation of the base class:

```
 public abstract class MyBaseClass 
 {

     private IMyOverridablePackage _overridablePackage;

     public void A()
     {
         _overridablePackage.A_Override();
     }

     public void B()
     {
         _overridablePackage.B_Override();
     }


     private class MyDefaultPackage : IMyOverridablePackage
     {
         private readonly MyBaseClass _myBaseClass;

         internal MyDefaultPackage(MyBaseClass myBaseClass) 
         {
             _myBaseClass = myBaseClass;
         }

         void IMyOverridablePackage.A_Override() 
         {
             _myBaseClass.A_Impl();
         }

         void IMyOverridablePackage.B_Override()
         {
             _myBaseClass.B_Impl();
         }
     }

     protected MyBaseClass()
     {
         _overridablePackage = new MyDefaultPackage(this);
     }

     private void A_Impl()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("MyBaseClass.A_Impl");
     }

     private void B_Impl()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("MyBaseClass.B_Impl");
     }

     protected void SetOverride(IMyOverridablePackage overridablePackage)
     {
         _overridablePackage = overridablePackage;
     }
 }
```

This does achieve the goal, but of course you have to ask 'how much to I want it?' Is it worth the extra code?

Here's a working dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xmPn20

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cannot force it via compiler errors, but you could write a test which asserts that the methods are in sync via some attributes. It would also be visible that there is some dependency.

A crude example would be something like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class VersionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public VersionAttribute(string version)
    {
        Version = version;
    }

    public string Version { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class DependentAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string DependentOnMethod { get; set; }
    public string DependentOnVersion { get; set; }
}


[Dependent(DependentOnMethod = "OtherMethod", DependentOnVersion = "1")]
public static void FirstMethod()
{
}

[Version("1")]
public static void OtherMethod()
{
}
```

And the test that asserts the version numbers:

```
[Test]
public void TestVersions()
{
    foreach (var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
    {
        foreach (var method in type.GetMethods())
        {
            foreach (var customAttribute in method.GetCustomAttributes())
            {
                var dependent = customAttribute as DependentAttribute;
                if (dependent != null)
                {
                    var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(dependent.DependentOnMethod);
                    Assert.That(methodInfo, Is.Not.Null, "Dependent method not found");
                    VersionAttribute version = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<VersionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
                    Assert.That(version, Is.Not.Null, "No version attribute on dependent method");
                    Assert.That(dependent.DependentOnVersion, Is.EqualTo(version.Version));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thus, if you update one of your methods you would need to update the version number of either the `Version` attribute or the `Dependent` attribute. Hopefully better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may change your design :

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected abstract void A();
}

public class BaseClassEx
{
    protected sealed override void A()
    { 
        // action Calling B
    }

    protected virtual void B()
    { 
        // a default action called second
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `Equals` (actually both Equals overloads, concrete type and object) and `GetHashCode`, Resharper includes a rule that shows a warning in its IntelliSense whenever you forget to implement one of these.

You could enforce it in your code with a runtime check in the constructor of the base class:

```
public class Base
{
  public Base()
  {
    var baseA = typeof (Base).GetRuntimeMethod("MethodA", new Type[0]);
    var baseB = typeof (Base).GetRuntimeMethod("MethodB", new Type[0]);
    var derivedA = GetType().GetRuntimeMethod("MethodA", new Type[0]);
    var derivedB = GetType().GetRuntimeMethod("MethodB", new Type[0]);

    if (baseA.DeclaringType == derivedA.DeclaringType ^ 
        baseB.DeclaringType == derivedB.DeclaringType)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("You must override MethodA and MethodB together.");
  }

  public virtual string MethodA() { return "Hello"; }
  public virtual int MethodB() { return 123; }
}
```